# iTunes Connect > Submit a Build > Plus icon not available

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit a build using the iTunes Connect web application.

I see this:

[image]

but according to this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW11
I should see a plus icon to the right of the word Build.

I don't see this nor do I see a Build listed in the Build section.

Why isn't it there?

Note - I do see two Builds in the Prerelease section but I'm not clear how you copy them over.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also getting same error.

Comment: Same problem here, there should be a plus sign.  Apple has messed something up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue.  You need to give the system some time to replicate after you've submitted your binary.  I needed to wait like 30 minutes before the "+" icon appeared and I was able to select the binary.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the page source you will see this:

`<a href="" ng-click="showBuildPicker()" class="addIcon ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="showBuildPickerIcon()">Add</a>`

`ng-hide` is an AngularJS property.  It looks like something has gone wrong.  For some reason the "Add" button is getting hidden.